# Bootstrap PUSH vs PULL vs OFFSET?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am new to Bootstrap. When I come across example in internet, I saw Push, pull and offset.When I google there is only explanation for push and offset, in bootstrap documentation I cant't get it clearly . What is the major difference between them and when to use these three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In offseting--Move columns to the right using .col-md-offset-* classes.
And through pull and push, Easily change the order of our built-in grid columns with .col-md-push-* and .col-md-pull-* modifier classes.